# Why tax_query in WP_Query not working

Tags: wp-query

I am using this code to get all posts under the category (name: 'Quizes', slug:'quizes'), which is a customized taxonomy (the slug is st_ai_cat).

```
// the query
$term_name = get_query_var('taxonomy'); // current taxonomy
$cat_name = get_query_var( 'term' ); // curent cat name
    
    echo $term_name;
    echo $cat_name;
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'st_ai',
                               'post_status' => 'publish',
                               'tax_query' => array(
                                   array(
                                      'taxonomy' => $term_name,
                                      'field' => 'slug',
                                      'term' => $cat_name,
                                   )
                               )
                               ));
    
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo "good";
}
?>
```

But it always shows nothing. If I remove tax_query, then it can show all posts under the customized taxonomy. But i want to only get posts under the category of Quizes. Why this happens? I checked its usage again.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change $cat_name by the category ID.

```
$term_name = get_query_var('taxonomy'); // current taxonomy
$cate = get_queried_object();
$cat_id = $cate->term_id; // current category ID
    
    echo $term_name;
    echo $cat_id;
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'st_ai',
                               'post_status' => 'publish',
                               'tax_query' => array(
                                   array(
                                      'taxonomy' => $term_name,
                                      'field' => 'slug',
                                      'term' => $cat_id,
                                   )
                               )
                               ));
    
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo "good";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, just `field` needs to be `'field' => 'id'.`

Comment: In my case, `$cat_name = get_query_var( 'term' );` should have the `'field' => 'name'`. Then it would work. Though I don't know why.

Comment: You are right. Have a good job and a good day

Comment: Thanks! You too.